# Man in the middle attack to a website which uses public key pinning

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

As far as I know, an attacker can intercept an encrypted traffic by adding custom certificate and CA authority into a victim's browser. I wonder if it works if a website uses public key pinning?

I added Burp's certificate to Firefox and I can access Facebook without any certificate error. How is it possible?

Comment: Does Facebook use public key pinning? It's not in the list at https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json of pre-defined pins. Can you access Twitter or Gmail through your setup - both of which are in that list.

Answer (score 9):

> I wonder if it works if a website uses public key pinning?

Yes it does. A certificate which is signed by a CA which was explicitly added to the trust store will not be affected by the pinning checks. This is deliberately done to allow useful and legal SSL interception. Such interception can be found in most enterprise firewalls but also lots of desktop AV and is needed to scan HTTPS traffic for malware etc. If this would not be done malware delivery would simply move to HTTPS (which is cheap enough).

Comment: I know these man-in-the-middle attacks are worded as "legal SSL interception" but they clearly violate the spirit of the TLS and the TRUST of the users in the standards.

"The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.2" (RFC 5246) clearly states "The TLS protocol provides communications security over the Internet" this "legal SSL interception" breaks down trust.

Comment: @jwilleke:  Yes, both legal SSL interception and malware are bad. You have to decide what is more relevant to you and most companies decide that the problems associated with SSL interception are less relevant than the risk of malware transported using HTTPS. Of course you can also block all traffic you cannot inspect (i.e. all HTTPS) but this would probably be considered even worse by most.

Comment: Is it really one or the other? I would rather TLS do as the RFC says and encourage trust instead of erode trust.

Comment: @jwilleke: Within your own network it is your personal risk decision. Within a company network you can either agree to interception or not use the companies internet. If you have a working solution which offers deep enough analysis of TLS traffic without doing man in the middle you probably get a reward for breaking TLS.

Comment: The Firefox documentation page which covers this is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning - specifically "Firefox (and Chrome) disable Pin Validation for Pinned Hosts whose validated certificate chain terminates at a user-defined trust anchor (rather than a built-in trust anchor). This means that for users who imported custom root certificates all pinning violations are ignored."

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Trust is being degraded because even if you and I understand what is a happening, the rest of the world does not. There is nothing transparent in what is happening with these "legal SSL interceptions". TLS RFC Clearly states "The TLS protocol provides communications security over the Internet".

Comment: @jwilleke: there might be many points to this issue and I just find another one more important than you: what is the trust in end-to-end encryption worth if it leads to increased risks of malware or data leakage? Companies have to make a decision to lower the risks and they don't care if they miss the point, they only care about reducing the risk. If you find a way to lower the risks to the same level while at the same time keeping end-to-end encryption they would probably be glad to do this instead.

Comment: The request/response is still encrypted with TLS after it leaves the corporate perimeter so I don't understand what the issue is. Corporate network has full visibility into packets on its own network. The rest of the world sees a normally encrypted TLS packet. The MITM happens inside the corporate perimeter, which is a private network. Not sure where trust is being degraded here, since a stipulation of using corporate network is being watched by corporate network admin.

Answer (score 3):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning):

> Firefox and Chrome disable pin validation for pinned hosts whose validated certificate chain terminates at a user-defined trust anchor (rather than a built-in trust anchor). This means that for users who imported custom root certificates all pinning violations are ignored.